# I need to know if this is correct. Set Theory

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So if I have set a = {1,2} and set b {2,1}

(a-b)-(b-a) What would be the resulting product?

Comment: The empty set.  Order doesn't matter in sets, so a = b.  a-b=b-a = a-a = b-b the empty set.  So empty set - empty set = empty set.

Answer (score 2):

If by $a-b$ you mean set $a$ without the elements in set $b$, then the answer if the empty set, because both sets have the same elements.

Comment: Yeah but is 1,2 and 2,1 two distinct sets? such as a{{1,2}} and b{{2,1}} so they are two different sets. Thus set a={c} minus b={d} is still c. right?

Comment: Order of elements doesn't matter in sets.

Comment: No, they are not distinct sets.  {1,2} and {2,1} are the exact same set.  Order does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

$a-b := \{x\in a \space AND \space x\notin b \} = \{\}$

$b-a := \{x\in b \space AND \space x\notin a \} = \{\}$

$\implies (a-b)-(b-a)=\{\}-\{\}=\{\}$

Answer (score 1):

In my living room I have three books.  "Moby Dick", "Horton Hears a Who" and "Pink Honk-Honk".  My roommate came around and shuffled them into a different order.  Now my three books are "Horton Hears a Who", "Moby Dick", and "Pink Honk-Honk".

Has anything changed?  I still have the same three books in my living room.

Let A = {the books in my living room} = {"Moby Dick", "Horton Hears a Who", "Pink Honk-Honk"}

Let B = {the books in my living room} = {"Horton Hears a Who", "Moby Dick", "Pink Honk-Honk"}

Are these sets any different?

...

Anyhoo...

What is $A - B$.  Well we start with A= {"Moby Dick", "Horton Hears a Who", "Pink Honk-Honk"} and we must remove B which is {"Horton Hears a Who", "Moby Dick", "Pink Honk-Honk"}

So first we remove "Horton Hears a Who".  That leaves us with {"Moby Dick", "Pink Honk-Honk"}

Then we remove "Moby Dick" that leaves us with {"Pink Honk-Honk"}.

Then we remove "Pink Honk-Honk" and that leaves us with {}.

So A - B = {}.

Now what is B - A?  We start with B = {"Horton Hears a Who", "Moby Dick", "Pink Honk-Honk"} and we must remove A which is {"Moby Dick", "Horton Hears a Who", "Pink Honk-Honk"}.

First we remove "Moby Dick" which leaves us with {"Horton Hears a Who", "Pink Honk-Honk"}

Then we remove "Horton Hears a Who" which leaves us with {"Pink Honk-Honk"}.

Then we remove "Pink Honk-Honk" which leaves us with {}.

So B - A = {}.

What is {} - {}?

Well we start with nothing and we remove nothing leaving us with nothing.

(A-B) - (B-A) = {}-{} = {}.

By now I hope I hammered it home that A = B = {books in my living room} = {the same god-damned books no matter what f#@$ing order they are in}.

So if A = {1,2} and B = {1,2} then {1,2} = {2,1} because order doesn't f@#$ing matter, so A = B.

So (A-B) - (B-A) = (A-A) - (A-A) = $\emptyset -\emptyset = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Just elaborating on comments and existing answers, to maybe clarify your understanding of why order of elements doesn't matter in sets:
Note that if $ A = \{1,2\}$ and $ B = \{2,1\}$
we have that $A \subset B$ since $\forall x \in A$ $x\in B$
and similarly $B \subset A$.

Thus $A=B$. (this is pretty much the axiom of extensionality in the ZFC axiom scheme)

Then of course that $A / B = \emptyset$

So $(A/B)/(B/A) = \emptyset$